# Select from multiple tables without using join and union

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.id as id,
       t1.username as username,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', t2.ad,t2.soyad) as fullname,
       t2.title as title,
       t3.pass as password,
       t3.phone_login as hat,
       t2.time as date
FROM kullanici t1, kullanici_tanim t2, dial_users t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.usr_id AND t1.agent_id = t3.user_id
GROUP  BY  t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

This query works fine. What I'm wondering is should I use joins? What is the correct way?

Comment: Use `JOIN`s; you technically already are with the conditions in your `WHERE` clause, but you are doing so in an archaic and painful to read manner.

Comment: If works fine what is the problem .... just a tip... Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: even both will give same result as of now you are using Cross Join with where condition where as in Join condition you will filter by required columns

Comment: The modern JOIN syntax separates the link-criteria from the filter-criteria. Which makes it harder to forget a link-criteria and end up with a nasty cartesian product join.

Comment: Comma means ("implicit") cross join with lower precedence than ("explicit") keyword joins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Answer (score 0):

For those who will have to use your code, please use joins. E.g.:

```
SELECT   t1.id as id,
             t1.username as username,
             CONCAT_WS(' ', t2.ad,t2.soyad) as fullname,
             t2.title as title,
             t3.pass as password,
             t3.phone_login as hat,
             t2.time as date
FROM kullanici t1 
     INNER JOIN kullanici_tanim t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.usr_id 
     INNER JOIN dial_users t3
     ON t1.agent_id = t3.user_id
GROUP  BY  t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

Comment: when I delete "GROUP  BY  t1.id", i get every row twice. how can i get one for every id without group by?

Comment: Why do you want to not use GROUP BY?

Comment: I want to learn if it is possible to get only one result per row without group by?

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: Comma is also  "ANSI-92-compliant code".